# Once an Unused Dialog is used, where does it go?

Tags: advanced-installer

I am a total newbie to Advanced Installer, so if this is a silly question, please forgive me.

I am trying to create a custom dialog box. In the Unused Dialogs, I copied an existing dialog, renamed it and modified it. Then, in another dialog in the sequence, I added a button. If that button is clicked, I set it to open the new dialog that I just created.

Here's the thing, as soon as I "use" the dialog by setting a button to open it, it then vanishes from the Unused Dialogs section, and I can't find it. If I want to make edits to it, I need to un-use it so that I can see it, and then use it again.

Where does it go when I use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it collapsed under the dialog you are triggering it from Next button. This is how Advanced Installer works, it just tries to display all possible dialog chains you could walk through at install time. The dialogs are displayed under a tree like view.